# drawing arcs in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I don't have a specific code problem as such but I've been asked to create a globe onto which I can project export on import figure as arc leading to and from countries, similar to the weapons import and export demo on the google WebGL page. I am new to three.js and have managed to construct a basic globe but could do with a good tutorial on :
1.How to map country shape files onto this rather than the raster png
2.How to create the arc.

Sorry for the general post but I'd appreciate any help and pointers that people might have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for the arcs: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Earth-LatLon.html
(see functions `greatCircleFunction`, `convertLatLonToVec3`, `createSphereArc` and `drawCurve`)

Example for the shapes: https://makc3d.wordpress.com/2014/04/20/threejs-bar-chart-on-the-globe/ (see the [demo](http://makc.github.io/three.js/map2globe/demo.html))

Comment: I've also come across this which is gets quite a powerful result without as much coding http://www.delimited.io/blog/2015/5/16/interactive-webgl-globes-with-threejs-and-d3